# Delete repeated string in a string with no delimiter

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, delimiter

I'm using some output from another system which cannot be changed that requires me to tidy up the output on each iteration in a while loop.

Output from iteration 1: `John Smith`
Output from iteration 2: `John SmithJohn Smith`

How can I use Javascript to tidy up the outputs so that it is:

Output from iteration 1: `John Smith`
Output from iteration 2: `John Smith`

Current code:

```
var names = document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div[2]/div/div/div", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); 
var thisName = names.iterateNext(); 
var arr = [];

while (thisName) {
  arr.push(nameComplete);
  thisName = names.iterateNext();
}
console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
["Josh ParkerJosh Parker", "John SmithJohn Smith", "David JamesDavid James"]
```

Comment: Please include the data, the code, and the expected result.

Comment: Without any context, it's hard to offer relevant advice.

Comment: I've added the output and the code.

Comment: What will happen on iteration 3?  
Could there be iteration 3?
Will it give you 3 times the value, or is it possible it will append a different value?

Comment: How does this work?  
I mean: where does `nameComplete` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is doubled, and you simply need half the string, then use [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with the string length to take the first half.

```js
var names = ["Josh ParkerJosh Parker", "John SmithJohn Smith", "David JamesDavid James"]; 
var arr = [];

for (var thisName of names) {
  arr.push(thisName.slice(0, thisName.length/2));
}
console.log(arr);
```